# Salesforce Task update api not updating fields sometimes

Tags: rest-api, integration, tasks

We have our plugin on salesforce and we are calling salesforce task update api for updating the subject, comments etc.from our backend. 90% of the time it updates the comments whereas 10% of the time it is not updating the comment, the subject anyhow is always getting updated. Although we are receiving 204 success as a response. We are calling the api from our code by getting the task id and its details.

We got the task by calling the below api:

"url":"https://universaleducation.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/query/?q=Select%20ID%2C%20Subject%2C%20Description%2C%20whatId%2C%20ownerId%2C%20whoId%20from%20Task%20%20WHERE%20CallObject%20%3D%20'94b8e387-9ae8-4873-be52-1295e7a54580'"

"statusCode":200

"response":"{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Task","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Task/00TC5000005k20BMAQ"},"Id":"00TC5000005k20BMAQ","Subject":"Click to Call","Description":"_",","}

Then we update the same task as below although the comment section was not updated in this case and subject was updated (which we pass as description).

url
https://universaleducation.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Task/00TC5000005k20BMAQ

header
{"content-type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer xxxx","encoding":"UTF-8","Accept":"application/json"}

method PATCH

data
{"WhoId":"003C5000003gJKxIAM","WhatId":"500C5000002mhcEIAQ","Subject":"OUTBOUND Call | Customer Number: +919993330628","Description":"_\r\n\r\nDetails of the call: Time: 2022-03-10 17:19:55 +05:30 \n             Business Number: +912241947722 \n             Customer: +919993330628\n             Agent: +919471381787 \n             Call Type: Phone - +919471381787 \n             Call ID: 94b8e387-9ae8-4873-be52-1295e7a54580\r\n\r\nYou can download the call recording [https://konnect.knowlarity.com/konnect/api/v1/814121/94b8e387-9ae8-4873-be52-1295e7a54580"}](https://konnect.knowlarity.com/konnect/api/v1/814121/94b8e387-9ae8-4873-be52-1295e7a54580%22%7D)

attached screenshot as example for when it gets updated and when it does not. Kindly help to find the issue as this happens sometimes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have before save triggers or flows that might be touching the data before the DML is done?

Comment: @cropredy no as such we don't have, also we are just hitting the salesforce api to update